# Wrapper for Excel Interop that allows "good" programming

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

I'm fairly new to programming with `Interop.Excel` and may lack the experience, but why is it such a pain to program with it? Casting objects everywhere, more or less no documentation on the methods (at least not in the code) and every method seems to return objects, so there is no way of telling what it actually does. Also, all arguments are objects to begin with.

Is there any good wrapper library out there that provides basic functionality (writing to cells, reading, creating sheets, deleting sheets, basic formatting and layouting) and does this in a good, clean and understandable (and by that I mean: well-documented) way?

PS: Working with C# and .NET-3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using `EPPlus` and very happy with it. It's open source and free.
The owners offer support when ever it was required.

[EPPlus on codeplex](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439)

Note that `EPPlus` doesn't support Excel 2003 format. **.xlxs is supported while. xls is not.**

Comment: And I used http://npoi.codeplex.com/ in the past for XLS files (EPPlus handles XLSX). But I must admit it was still not flawless and becomes painful when you get to more advanced features. I am unable to compare it with Excel interop and other libraries, since I did not use any of them for any advanced tasks.

Comment: @Darjan. `npoi` has a series lack of functionality. I tried it, but simple things like colors are not supported...

Comment: EPPlus is very good. I recommend it! Decent OO programming style for dealing with Excel documents.

Comment: And adding a comment using `npoi` that would be collapsed (instead of expanded) when an Excel file is opened was ... a no go (it's a known issue).

Answer (score 2):

Well this is quite pricey, but in my opinion worth the money if you are doing serious commercial work with excel. As well as being the fastest option, you also don't even have to have excel installed, anyone who has run excel on a server will understand why that is huge.

[Http://www.spreadsheetgear.com](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com)

Answer (score 1):

If you're having problems with using interop directly, you may want to try out [OfficeWriter](http://www.officewriter.com). It can do anything you've described above with Excel, and more. You can request a free trial. There's a fully documented api available at the [documentation site](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/Docs/OfficeWriter+Docs).

DISCLAIMER: I'm one of the engineers who built the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com), it wraps the OpenXML SDK to give a very intuitive way to create Excel files.